# Is connectify traceable through my IP address?

Tags: connectify

i am using connectify on my laptop in my company. is it possible for it guy to trace that connectify is being used from my ip address? if it is then how can i stop him from tracing my activities over connectify?

Comment: If you are using a company laptop then your IT department can monitor everything that you do.

Comment: Can your "IT guy" tell you are using Connectify.  Absustely, your "IT guy" can indeed, and since you don't have the required permissions to stop him, there isn't anything you can do to prevent that.

Answer (score 2):

As DavidPostill said - if you are using a company computer (or any computer on a company network) - your IT Admins can see everything you do - providing they have monitoring in place.

Regardless of what you are up to - your internet traffic goes out through their firewalls, proxies and routers.  Your internal traffic goes through their switches and routers.

If your IT Dept has the ability to port-mirror, gather proxy logs, monitor firewalls, then everything you do can be watched.

If what you are doing is really that secret that you don't want your IT dept/boss to know - then don't do it at work.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using a VPN to another point (which I highly doubt), everything is traceable. The IT dept can see everything, emphasize everything, on the network. Did these stuff myself